# jQuery Ajax Render Fragments OR Whole Page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm in the throes of building an application that wraps a mess of legacy code.  For the page I am working on, I need to substitute fragment divs constructed on my back-end -- or else I need to replace the entire page altogether.  The idea is that there is a dynamically controlled flow that needs to be satisfied before we can forward to the legacy product.

Substituting fragments works fine, as seen in the below `my_body_content` swap.  The trouble comes when what I'm trying to render is **not** a fragment, but the whole page, as in the "body" swap.  At this point the page goes blank.

I also want to do something similar with errors returned from the server.  I want my nice `REST 404` error messages to be displayed on the screen, but for legacy-product 404s to show in the legacy-product 404 page.

Yes, the requirements for this project are weird.  That's not a problem I can fix.

Here's my jQuery invocation, with names changed to protect the guilty:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "places/things",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(someBadAssObject),
    dataType: "text",
    accepts: "text/html",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(x) {
        var fragcheck = $("#my_fragment", x);
        if (fragcheck != null && fragcheck.length > 0)
            $("#my_body_content").html(x);
        else
            $("body").html(x);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        error(errorThrown);
        if (XMLHttpRequest.responseText.startsWith("<html>"))
            $("body").html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: I should probably mention ... the legacy app makes extensive use of frames, and I'm wondering if somehow these frames need to be forced somehow, or if this is going to work at all with frames.

Comment: Okay, I think I can answer my own question, except that I can't answer my own question due to stackoverflow rules.  Arg.

Comment: Basically, the answer lies in replacing the "$('body').html(x)" with document.open(); document.write(x); document.close().  I'll post the nicer-ly formatted result in, oh, 8 hours or more ;P

Comment: This is generally not standard or good practice because ajax is meant to only send back partials or data, and js rendering pages feels pretty hacky... but I had a use for it. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I can answer my own question:

```
$("body").html(x);
```

doesn't work, and

```
$("html").replaceWith(x);
```

doesn't work, and other permutations along the same idea don't work either.

This works:

```
document.open();
document.write(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
document.close();
```

So the whole solution looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "places/things",
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(someBadAssObject),
dataType: "text",
accepts: "text/html",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(x) {
    var fragcheck = $("#my_fragment", x);
    if (fragcheck != null && fragcheck.length > 0)
        $("#my_body_content").html(x);
    else
    {
        document.open();
        document.write(x);
        document.close();
    }
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    error(errorThrown);
    if (XMLHttpRequest.responseText.startsWith("<html>"))
    {
        document.open();
        document.write(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

});

Hope this helps the next poor schmoe!